# Firefox: How to get my home page in new tabs, instead of the recent sites 'tiles' thing :(

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 25 (running on Windows 7), I have the following Startup settings:

- When Firefox starts = 'Show my home page'
- Home Page = (URL of the site I want)

So when I click on the Home button, I get the right page. That's all good.

However, when I open a new tab, I get the 'recently visited websites tiles' screen, i.e. this:

[image: Screenshot].

How do I get Firefox to show my Home Page in new tabs as well??

**Note**: when I open a new *Window*, it works OK. I'm getting the Home Page there. The problem is just with New Tab!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways with different effects:

1. Right-click and Modify **browser.newtab.url** to **about:home** in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config). To revert, right-click and Reset.
2. [Add the site/home page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites#w_add-a-site) as one among the others in the new tab. Optionally [pin it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites#w_pin-a-site) to make it permanently available. It's also possible to open the site/home page and add it by dragging the site icon (left edge of the navigation/address bar) into a tile inside the new tab.

[about:config Entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)